# Dynamic Column in JSF Datatable JSF2.0

Tags: jsf, dynamic, jsf-2, datatable

I need one help from you. I am using JSF 2.0 and I have a datatable component . One of the column in the datatable is an action column and I need to create a toolbar which contains different type of actionsource component such as command button, link etc. The type of actionsource is determined at run time and number of actionsource is also done at run time. How I can implement this in JSF 2.0

```
           <p:dataTable value="#{listBranchBean1.rowDataModel}" var="rowItem"
              id="myId" paginator="true"
              paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink}{PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}{RowsPerPageDropdown} "
              rowsPerPageTemplate="10,5,2" previousPageLinkLabel="&lt;"
              nextPageLinkLabel="&gt;" widgetVar="branchTable"
              selection="#{listBranchBean1.selectedBranchesPrime}"
              resizableColumns="true"
              sortBy="#{rowItem.columnsValueMap['branchId'].value}">
              <f:facet name="header">
                 <p:outputPanel>
                    <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
                    <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="branchTable.filter()"
                       style="width:150px" />
                 </p:outputPanel>
              </f:facet>
              <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="text-align:left">
                 <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Select" />
                 </f:facet>
                 <h:outputText value="#{rowItem.uniqueId}" />
              </p:column>
              <p:column
                 rendered="#{listBranchBean1.columnsMap['objectId'].hidden==false}"
                 sortBy="#{rowItem.columnsValueMap['objectId'].value}"
                 filterBy="#{rowItem.columnsValueMap['objectId'].value}">
                 <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText
                       value="#{listBranchBean1.columnsMap['objectId'].displayLabel}" />
                 </f:facet>
                 <h:outputText
                    value="#{rowItem.columnsValueMap['objectId'].value}" />
              </p:column>
              <p:column
                 rendered="#{listBranchBean1.columnsMap['actions'].hidden==false}">
                 <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText
                       value="#{listBranchBean1.columnsMap['actions'].displayLabel}" />
                 </f:facet>
                 <p:toolbar>
                    <p:toolbarGroup>
                       <ui:repeat var="action"
                          value="#{rowItem.columnsValueMap['actions'].value}">
                          <p:commandButton title="#{action}" type="button">
                          </p:commandButton>
                       </ui:repeat>
                    </p:toolbarGroup>

                 </p:toolbar>
              </p:column>
           </p:dataTable>
```

I want to replace the last column with something like

```
                 <p:toolbar binding="#{listBranchBean1.getActions(rowItem)}">
                 </p:toolbar>
```

I appreciate your help

Prajeesh Nair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between build-time and render-time in JSF. Build-time tags like `<ui:repeat>` have the ability to create new components dynamically, but they can only use data that is available at build-time.

However, using Java you are also allowed to alter the component tree programmatically, but this too can not just happen at any moment. The safe moment to do this is the `preRenderViewEvent`, which is a good bit later than the build-time moment (which is the `restore view` phase) and you should have all the data you need by then.

Inside an event handler for this event you can reference the tool bar you bound to your backing bean, and programmatically add columns to it.

For examples see:

- http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2006/06/using-datatables.html#PopulateDynamicDatatable
- http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2011/09/authoring-jsf-pages-in-pure-java.html

Do note that if your backing bean is `@ViewScoped`, you'd better not use binding but use a manual lookup instead. This is due to some bugs with respect to the view scope and binding components in JSF.

Comment: 1. The scope can be defined by the end user as it is a customizable solution. As of now it is a ViewScope. If you see may last column, the rowItem is datatable var. So I need to get the action column specific to that row. it will be different for each row

Comment: If you need dynamic columns, use arjan's solution. If you also need dynamic content per row, put in multiple components and render them conditionally. You can't have arbitrary components per row in a data table, since rows don't really exists there (it are columns rendered with changing data). Maybe look at some datagrid component if you need that.

Answer (score 0):

below code will create dynamic column on the basis of selected country

```
public void loadDynamicList() throws Exception {
int i=0;
 dynamicList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
dynamicList.add(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "ID1" }));
existingCountryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
String countryCode="US";
existingCountryList.add(getCountryService().getCountryByCode(countryCode));
Country country=getCountryService().getCountryByCode(countryCode);
countryLanguageSet=country.getCountryLanguage();
i=country.getCountryLanguage().size();
dynamicHeaders = new String[i] ;
int j=0;
   for (CountryLanguage count: countryLanguageSet) {
    System.out.println(count.getLanguage().getLanguageName());
    dynamicHeaders[j]=count.getLanguage().getLanguageName();
    j++;
}
 }
public void populateDynamicDataTable() {
debugLogger.debug("populateDynamicDataTable:Enter");
// Create <h:dataTable value="#{myBean.dynamicList}" var="dynamicItem">.
HtmlDataTable dynamicDataTable = new HtmlDataTable();
dynamicDataTable.setValueExpression("value", createValueExpression("#{relationBean.dynamicList}", List.class));
dynamicDataTable.setVar("dynamicItem");

// Iterate over columns.
for (int i = 0; i < dynamicHeaders.length; i++) {
    // Create <h:column>.
    HtmlColumn column = new HtmlColumn();
    dynamicDataTable.getChildren().add(column);
    // Create <h:outputText value="dynamicHeaders[i]"> for <f:facet name="header"> of column.
    HtmlOutputText header = new HtmlOutputText();
    header.setValue(dynamicHeaders[i]);
    column.setHeader(header);
     HtmlInputText input=new HtmlInputText();
    column.getChildren().add(input);
}
   dynamicDataTableGroup = new HtmlPanelGroup();
dynamicDataTableGroup.getChildren().add(dynamicDataTable);
debugLogger.debug("populateDynamicDataTable:Exit");
}

public HtmlPanelGroup getDynamicDataTableGroup() throws Exception {
// This will be called once in the first RESTORE VIEW phase.
if (dynamicDataTableGroup == null) {
    loadDynamicList(); // Preload dynamic list.
    populateDynamicDataTable(); // Populate editable datatable.
}

return dynamicDataTableGroup;
}


public List<List<String>> getDynamicList() {
return dynamicList;
}
public void setDynamicList(List<List<String>> dynamicList) {
this.dynamicList = dynamicList;
}

public void setDynamicDataTableGroup(HtmlPanelGroup dynamicDataTableGroup) {
this.dynamicDataTableGroup = dynamicDataTableGroup;
}

public ValueExpression createValueExpression(String valueExpression, Class<?> valueType) {
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
return facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(
    facesContext.getELContext(), valueExpression, valueType);
}
```